# Cannot access winsat data from WWI using c#

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, system.management

I am trying to access winsat data . WMI has a class for it .

```
Win32_WinSAT
```

I am trying to get that recent data using query

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_WinSAT WHERE TimeTaken='MostRecentAssessment'"
```

It will work fine in PowerShell and even in WMIExplorer
But it is not working in C# code using System.Management class

My code is as follows

```
class WinSatData
    {
        public double MemoryScore { get; set; }
        public double CPUScore { get; set; }
        public double D3DScore { get; set; }
        public double DiskScore { get; set; }
        public double GraphicsScore { get; set; }
    }
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<WinSatData> winsat = new List<WinSatData>();
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\localhost\\root\\cimv2");
            scope.Connect();

            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_WinSAT WHERE TimeTaken='MostRecentAssessment'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject m in collection) {
                WinSatData win = new WinSatData();
                win.CPUScore = (Convert.ToDouble(m["CPUScore"]));
                win.MemoryScore = (Convert.ToDouble(m["MemoryScore"]));
                win.D3DScore = (Convert.ToDouble(m["D3DScore"]));
                win.GraphicsScore = (Convert.ToDouble(m["GraphicsScore"]));
                winsat.Add(win);
            }
            string outout = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(winsat);
            Console.WriteLine(outout);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

All the values in the Management object are zero . I carefully went through the properties of ManagementObject m . Property name is right but value is wrong.

Output is as follows:

```
[{"MemoryScore":0.0,"CPUScore":0.0,"D3DScore":0.0,"DiskScore":0.0,"GraphicsScore":0.0}]
```

Please help me access WinSAT.

Comment: which windows are you using? and is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bit . Its a platform issue. I am forcing a 32 bit wmi query on a 64 bit machine . I am trying to find a work around.

Comment: that's weird tested on win7 64 bit and win 10 32 bit ,both work fine

Comment: I can't figure out what is happening . Code seems to work fine on other systems .